# Some of my input fields are not being posted to php

Tags: php, html, post

I'm writing a school project where we are making an IMDB-esque site. I'm trying to add comments to our database, but two of my fields (fid and spoiler specifically) are not being posted to the php handling the database.

```html
<table>
    <form name="komment" method="post" action="addComment.php">
    <tr>[Username]</tr>
        <td><input type="textarea" name="text"> </td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit"> </td>
        <td>Spoiler? <input type="checkbox" name="spoiler"></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="fid" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="[Username]">
    </form>
</table>
```

Here's the php, sorry about it, I was asleep

```html
<?php
header("filmSingle.php");
$filmID = $_POST["fid"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$text = $_POST["text"];
$spoiler = $_POST["spoiler"];

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    echo $key."=>".$value."<br>";
}

include "dbconnection.php";
$connection = DBconnection::getInstance(DBconnection::$database_name);
$arguments = array("Spoiler"=>$spoiler, "Szoveg"=>$text, "Film_id"=>$filmID, "Felhasznalo"=>$username);
$connection->insertInto("hozzaszolas", $arguments);



exit();
```

Also the output:
Notice: Undefined index: fid in C:\xampp\htdocs\film\addComment.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\film\addComment.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: spoiler in C:\xampp\htdocs\film\addComment.php on line 6
text=>test
submit=>Submit

Comment: There's no "php" here.

Comment: `<form>` cannot be made a child of `<table>`.

Comment: The checkbox has no value.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Checkboxes have default `value="on"`

Comment: Add your php code

Comment: @Barmar Ok fair enough. So I don't know why they have it and how they're using it and checking for `if ?=="on"` (pseudo). The question was for me, an entire typographical error code and possibly for others also who may not have seen this question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner There's other HTML problems, see my answer.

Comment: @Barmar I noticed. [I also mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58634446/some-of-my-input-fields-are-not-being-posted-to-php?noredirect=1#comment103575825_58634446) the thing about table/form if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I saw that, but it was more than that, he was also missing lots of `<tr>` and `<td>` tags.

Comment: @Barmar Ok. However and thing is; why did the OP make an edit by adding the "php" and undefined index notices? Is the question completely solved or not?

Comment: The question is solved, commenters wanted to see my php code so I put it in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the table inside the form, not a form inside the table.

The children of `<table>` can only be table elements such as `<tbody>` and `<tr>`.

And all the `<td>` elements need to be in `<tr>`.

```html
<form name="komment" method="post" action="addComment.php">
  <table>
    <tr><td>[Username]</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="textarea" name="text"> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit"> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Spoiler? <input type="checkbox" name="spoiler"></td></tr>
    <tr><input type="hidden" name="fid" value="1"></tr>
    <tr><input type="hidden" name="username" value="[Username]"></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You also need to have `<tr>...</tr>` around all the other `<td>` elements.